# Getting wrong keys in json while calling retrofit after enabling proguard

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, okhttp

when i call retrofit **without proguard** i got json like following :
`D/OkHttp: {"UserPin":"123456","password":"123456"}`
and after **adding proguard** it gives following json :
`D/OkHttp: {"a":"123456","b":"123456"}`

Proguard changes the keys in json

This is my code:-

```
private void doLogin(String userPin, String password) {
        startProgress();
        LoginUser loginUser = new LoginUser(userPin, password);
        Call<Login> call = MyApplication.apiInterface.doLogin(loginUser);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
                finishProgress();
                try {
                    setLoginResponse(response.body());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
                finishProgress();
                try {
                    setLoginResponse(null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Please help me

Comment: Solved this yet ?

Comment: I had already put all POJO classes in Proguard, but missed to add base package of models in proguard. I just simply add `
-keep class com.example.test.** { *; }` with having all POJO classes in proguard like `
-keep class com.assettagging.test.LoginUser** { *; }` and it worked.

Comment: Kindly review my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should add **`proguard`** rule.

```
-ignorewarnings
-dontwarn okio.**

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

And Login class

```
-keep class package_name.Login** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class package_name.Login** { *; }
```

For [**`GSON Proguard`**](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg), Try this

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure are have proguard configured for gson, too. You need to make sure POJO used with gson are not obfuscated and annotations are not stripped.

**Note:** You should replace `com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }` with your model classes in the example below.

From the gson example proguard config --

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```